# Getting 250+ items but Custom Listview not displaying anything

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I just created a list view with a custom view to create a country list for select

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".RnActivity.RnView.RnUser.ActivitySignUpOptions">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/country_list_for_select_list_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**custom view**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_layout_country_list_item_country_icon_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/gjh_logo_b"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_layout_country_list_item_country_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="India"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_layout_country_list_item_country_code"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="IN"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**In Activity**

```
ListView country_list_for_select_list_area;
    @Override
    public void lodeControls() {
        country_list_for_select_list_area=findViewById(R.id.country_list_for_select_list_area);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEvents() {

    }

    RxAdopterCountry countryAdopter;
    @Override
    public void createAdopters() {
        countryAdopter=new RxAdopterCountry(getActivity(),R.layout.view_layout_country_list_item, RsXtraCountryList.getInstance().getCountryList());
    }

    @Override
    public void setData() {
        country_list_for_select_list_area.setAdapter(countryAdopter);
    }
```

**In Adopter**

```
private final ArrayList<RentCountry> countryList;
private Context context;


public RxAdopterCountry(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<RentCountry> countryList) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.context=context;
    this.countryList=countryList;
}


public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_country_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView view_layout_country_list_item_country_icon_image=convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_layout_country_list_item_country_icon_image);
    TextView view_layout_country_list_item_country_name=convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_layout_country_list_item_country_name);
    TextView view_layout_country_list_item_country_code=convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_layout_country_list_item_country_code);

    view_layout_country_list_item_country_name.setText(countryList.get(position).getName());
    view_layout_country_list_item_country_code.setText(countryList.get(position).getCode());
    view_layout_country_list_item_country_icon_image.setImageResource(countryList.get(position).getFlag_id());
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

i debugged the whole code and there are 250 items are coming in

```
private final ArrayList<RentCountry> countryList;
```

but list view is showing nothing

What I am doing wrong? I tried everything and debugged the whole code 10 times. yes I am getting the data in the ArrayList bu still noting is appearing in the list view.
Please help

Comment: in your adapter, try `super(context, resource, countryList);` in constructor

Comment: @PhanVanLinh still getting an error but yes after this finally got the response from the view area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are returning `super.getView(position, convertView, parent)` from `getView` while you should be returning the `View` you just created that is `convertView` .
For  super constructor call you have to use `super(context, resource, countryList)` so that Adapter can return the size of list.

Change `getView`  like below

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    //...
    return convertView;
}
```

Also you should be using `RecyclerView` now. `ListView` and `GridView` are legacy widgets for a long time .  `RecyclerView` is much more flexible.